# What punctuation should I use to connect "I was reminded of something Sara had said" and "that people are often..."?

Tags: punctuation, clauses

There's a sentence I wanted to write but I don't know which punctuation mark goes between these clauses:

"I was reminded of something Sara had said" and "that people are often..."

Would it be a dash, comma or semicolon?

Comment: As a writer it's your option to decide whether **Sara had said** is essential or nonessential. Consequently, you may want to use either a pair of commas or no comma.

Answer (score 1):

A comma would be fine:

> I was reminded of something Sara had said, that people are often . . .

We could consider the nominal clause "that people are often . . ." to be in apposition to "something Sara had said".

Because "that people are often . . ." provides further information about "something Sara had said", we could also use a colon:

> I was reminded of something Sara had said: that people are often . . .

However, a semicolon would not be appropriate. That mark is used mostly to connect independent clauses or to separate items in lists.

Comment: Colon is the cleanest, imo. Dash would also be okay. Comma is borderline. As you wrote, semicolon is out.

Answer (score 0):

A comma would be sufficient.  There is an example of this us from [News 24.com](https://www.news24.com/you/Archive/solange-knowles-overreacted-to-jay-zs-comment-20170728)

> Solange flipped out over something Jay had said, that she took the wrong way.

I suppose a colon (without starting a new sentence and without a capital letter) would also be possible. Colons can often be read as "namely" or "that is".

The second clause is not independent, so a semicolon would not be correct.

If the last part is intended to be an exact quote, then quote marks should be used, and you don't need the word "that".

> I was reminded of something Sara had said, “People are often...”

Comment: I'm slightly confused. In the example you shared, the second clause isn't actually the thing that Jay said, if I'm correct. It's just saying that Solange took whatever he was saying the wrong way. I don't know if I'm making much sense, but I feel like the example I gave is of a different nature? The second clause if talking about what Sara actually said. You could still be right though

Comment: I'm assuming it is reported speech in both cases. The reporting is rather more of a paraphrase in  news24 example. If it is not reported speech I'd use quotation marks.  I'll edit.